# Web Widget - security and way of doing it

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a web widget for my page - meaning that a user can get any portion of my page as an iframe(is it good way of creating widget?) with some css styles he can set and he can paste the iframe code in his page.

my question is:

```
1. is the iframe solution good way of doing this? if not, what can be the other solution? 
2. what security issues should I take care of?
```

appreciate any help..

Comment: I have the feeling this will be primarily opinion based, but have you considered offering it by _ajax_ (possibly _JSONP_ for cross-domain) to be placed into a node of choice? Also, for _security_, never believe anything from a client!

Comment: Thanks Paul. I will study the ajax version which may be the better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the css styles are fixed and limited(say height, width, background, font-size), then you consider the following-

- Have a form with multiple fields where user can fill his desired    values for the properties  like width, height, background-color etc.
- generate a script with these inputs as query params e.g.-

`<script type="text/javascript" src="<your domain>/widget.js?height=<userinput>&width=<userinput>"></script`>

- this script can be copied and used by the user. The work of this script will to create a iframe widget with your desired html in it.